# Codeigniter: Unable to get a query string from the database into an array

Tags: codeigniter

My goal is to substitute a number for a query string -- and I'm trying to get the query string out of the database and insert it into an array so I can perform a search.

This file extended file is located in core/ called MY_Input.php

```
class MY_Input extends CI_Input {


   function save_query($query_array) {

    $CI =& get_instance();

    $CI->db->insert('ci_query', array('query_string' => http_build_query($query_array)));

    return $CI->db->insert_id();
}

function load_query($query_id) {

    $CI =& get_instance();

    $rows = $CI->db->get_where('ci_query', array('id' => $query_id))->result();
    if (isset($rows[0])) {
        parse_str($rows[0]->query_string, $_GET);       
    }

}

}
```

I'm grabbing the string from the database and trying to load it into my controler page like this:

```
this->input->load_query($query_id); 


    $query_array = array(
        'fan_type_options'=>$this->input->get('fan_type_options'),
        'fan_motor_type' => $this->input->get('fan_motor_type'),
        'fan_ac_voltage' => $this->input->get('fan_ac_voltage'),
        'fan_cfm' => $this->input->get('fan_cfm'),
        'part-no' => $this->input->get('part-no'),
    );
```

I When I dump the array, it has no values, but the first function works, and I'm able to capture the query string which looks like this:

```
fan_type_options=Blower&fan_motor_type=EC&fan_ac_voltage=&fan_cfm=&part-no=
```

But I can't figure out how to debug the second function. Can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong or if there is a way to debug the function.

Comment: Isn't the load query supposed to return a value? To debug you can use Print_r();  die();